# Passing value to jQuery UI Dialog for AJAX post on confirmation

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I'm using jQuery UI dialog to confirm the delete request. I'm trying to pass in an ID to an AJAX post when I user confirm a deletion request. Thank you in advance for any insight.

Here is HTML:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" border="0" class="detailTbl" id="myTable">
<tbody>
<tr class="divider" id="editRow220">
<td align="top">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </td>
<td align="top">                                    
    <a class="btn_delete deleteMe form-tip" href="#" id="220" title="Delete this item"></a>
    <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>                                         
</table>
```

Here is SCRIPT:

```
$("#myTable tbody").on("click", "a.deleteMe", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var RemoveID = $(this);
    alert(RemoveID.attr("id")); // ***correct ID here ***

    var $myDialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Confirmation',
            buttons: {"Yes": function(e) { 
            alert(RemoveID.attr("id")); // ***RemoveID is undefined here*** 
                // AJAX Call here //

                return true;
            }, "No": function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
                return false;
            }
  }
     });

    return $myDialog.dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: why arent you just capturing the id itself into the variable, rather than the entire object? `var RemoveID = $(this).attr('id');`

Comment: You wrote "return" before the $.post() function, use return (true or false) in callback

Comment: I don't think a dialog can be 'opened' if it is not a part of the DOM. E.g. `return $myDialog;` and at the line in your code where the dialog is returned to, say `$('body').append($myDialog); $myDialog.dialog('open');`

Comment: I just update the code, everything worked prior to utilizing jQuery UI dialog.

Comment: It works here is jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bphamous/rQ3MC/

Comment: @sdespont I return for troubleshooting purposes, I want to make sure the ID pass in is correct or not.

Comment: Ha, it appears to be working on jsFiddle. It maybe because I cleaned it up for this sample.Guess i'll have to verify my codes. thanks for your respond everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a sloppy solution, but can you try assigning the ID to a global variable, then using it:

```
var mID;

$("#myTable tbody").on("click", "a.deleteMe", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
mID = $(this).attr("id");

var $myDialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Confirmation',
        buttons: {"Yes": function(FmoPmoToRemove) { 
             alert(mID); //shouldnt be undefined anymore

..rest of code..
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple moch-up on jsFiddle www.jsfiddle.net/bphamous/rQ3MC and it appears to be working. Issue must be in my code.

Answer (score 0):

what is the problem when using cofirm() of Java script like this :

```
function delete(Id){
   boolean b = confirm("Deleting : "+Id", Are you sure ..??");
   if(b == true){
    // make the delete process here ...
   }
   else{
      // do dtuff .....
   }
 }
```

Comment: I had no problem with using Javascript confirm(). I was trying to within the jQuery UI dialog button function callback. I got it to work you can check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/bphamous/rQ3MC/10/.

Comment: listen .... in jquery ui dialog there is way to add buttons you can add cacnel button and programm it as 'cancel deleting' and you can add button delete and program it also to 'delete' got it ???